# Solving a sum of a function and the function $\sum_{k=1}^\text{n}f(k)=f(m)\space\Longleftrightarrow\space m=\dots$

Tags: number-theory, polynomials, summation, quadratics, natural-numbers

I've a quadratic equation:

$$f(m)=am^2+bm+c\tag1$$

Where $a,b,c\in\mathbb{R}$ (where $c$ can be zero), $m\in\mathbb{N}$ and $m\ge2$.

Is there a clever way of solving (where $\text{n}\in\mathbb{N}$ and $\text{n}\ge2$):

$$\sum_{k=1}^\text{n}f(k)=f(m)\space\Longleftrightarrow\space m=\dots\tag2$$

---

As an example we can look at: $f(m)=-\dfrac{m}{2}+\dfrac{3m^2}{2}$

Comment: Note for $f(x)=-\frac{x}{2}+\frac{3x^2}{2} = ax^2 + bx + c$, you now have $a = \frac{3}{2}$ and $b = -\frac{1}{2}$, but your question says $a, b, c \in \mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: @JohnOmielan Haha my mind is playing games with me I'm sorry. Now my question is correct!

Comment: I think the integer constraint would be more obvious if you used $m$ instead of $x$.

Comment: @YvesDaoust you can change it if you want

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are asking to solve the Diophantine equation

$$a\frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6}+ b\frac{n(n+1)}{2}+ cn=am^2+bm+c.$$

If some of the coefficients $a,b,c$ are incommensurable, the equation turns to a system. E.g.

$$\sqrt2\frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6}+\frac{n(n+1)}{2}=\sqrt2m^2+m$$ is equivalent to

$$\begin{cases}\dfrac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6}=m^2,\\\dfrac{n(n+1)}{2}=m\end{cases}$$

and a solution can exist if

$$\frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6}=\dfrac{n^2(n+1)^2}{4}.$$

The integer solutions are $n=-1,0,1$.

When the coefficients are commensurable, you can turn them to integers and I guess that the resulting equation is difficult.

Comment: Are those the only integer solutions or are there more?

Comment: @jan: isn't that obvious ? Solve the quadratic after simplification.

Comment: The resulting equation will be an elliptic curve for almost all commensurable $a$, $b$ and $c$. Difficult indeed.